# Change App Version while releasing to Play Store in Cordova

Tags: cordova, google-play

I am trying to update the apk on play store that is under beta but whenever I upload the apk I am getting below error.

```
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 10000.
```

I am using below command to generate key stroke file.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore example.keystore -alias example -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

I tried to changed the validity value to 10001 but it is still not working. Might be I am doing something wrong.

I am very new to it and have lack of knowledge.

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:versionCode="10001" android:versionName="1.0.1"
```

Now I am getting below error while uploading apk to play store.

```
You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into the future.
```

Comment: The community has discussed whether "home-made tags" can be put in titles, and the answer was [that we would rather they were not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076).  Please write your titles as a natural, flowing question as much as you can. We have a tagging system for tags proper.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change version code and version name in you app **build.gradle**. for every new apk uploaded to play console

Comment: nothing found inside build.gradle related to version code and name, remember i am using cordova.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the version code in your config.xml of your cordova project.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>    
<widget android-versionCode="1001" version="1.0.1 id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>HelloCordova</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a higher version value in config.xml, build your app and check android:versionCode value in your android project file androidmanifest.xml. If it's 10000 or less, then again increase version value.